# How to show n numbers of images in center of div

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a div inside which I am showing images. I have 1 to 5 images loaded from database dynamically. So the no. of images is not fixed. I want to center images inside div irrespective of their numbers.
Please HELP!!!!!!!!

```
<div class="sliderImg" style="width:975px; height:306px;text-align:center;">

                 <img id="img1" runat="server" visible="false" width="195" height="306" alt="slider">

                 <img id="img2" runat="server" visible="false" width="195" height="306" alt="slider">

                 <img id="img3" runat="server" visible="false" width="195" height="306" alt="slider">

                 <img id="img4" runat="server" visible="false" width="195" height="306" alt="slider">

                 <img id="img4" runat="server" visible="false" width="195" height="306" alt="slider">     





                    </div>
```

From code behind I set their visibility according to some conditions.

Comment: can you give some code in jsffidle

Comment: give us the code that you have so far

Comment: provide some code to understand your question properly.

Comment: Thanks to all the problem was with the top div i set its width to 912px that's why images were not aligning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

images are inline replaced elements, so no matter how many images are outputted, just be sure to have a `div` wide enough (to contain at least 5 images) and set `text-align: center` to it

Answer (score 0):

Without code you have already tried it's difficult to answer however something like the following might be what you're looking for:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's example for vertical and horizontal centering elements in custom div container.

**html:**

```
<div class="images">
    <!-- images -->
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
    <img src="#" />
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.images
{
    /* centering image */
    text-align: center;

    /* container size */
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;

    /* reset 'paddings' */
    font-size: 0;

    /* for example */
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.images img
{
    /* for centering image */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle

    /* image size */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px #f00 solid;

    /* for example */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

So, look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artem_fitiskin/saq6E/

Answer (score 0):

just do only one things in your css

```
.sliderImg{width:975px; height:306px;text-align:center;}
.sliderImg img{ display:block; margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
```

hope your problem will solved after using this.